# Do we need to compile code in ES5 to support IE 11 in angular 9?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I am working on an angular 9 app and I am wondering , do I need to still compile my code targeting es5 ( as IE 11 does not support ES6 still). The reason for asking this question is, As angular's differential loading feature will provide the es5 bundle to the browsers which does not support ES6.
I mean the build output of the angular 9 project already has files both in ES5 and ES6.
Do I still need to set the target: es5  in tsconfig.json?

My app need to support only IE11 and NOT any other version of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to update the `target` to `"es5"` for IE 11 since the IE11 only supports at best ES5.
And you can refer to this angular document:
https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Emon, you still need to set the target to ES 5. More detail information, please check the [Angular Browser support document](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support):

*In Angular CLI version 8 and higher, applications are built using differential loading, a strategy where the CLI builds two separate bundles as part of your deployed application.
The first bundle contains modern ES2015 syntax, takes advantage of built-in support in modern browsers, ships less polyfills, and results in a smaller bundle size.
The second bundle contains code in the old ES5 syntax, along with all necessary polyfills. This results in a larger bundle size, but supports older browsers.*

Comment: yes, and that's my question as we are already having two bundles , even if we do not set target to es5. and those bundles will be shipped to browser based on their support for ES6 or not. So why do we need to set the target to ES5 explicitly. if we do not do it than even we have ES5 bundle which IE11 will get it as it does not support ES6.

Comment: By default in version 8 and higher, we enable differential loading for ng build. However for `ng test` and `ng serve` we only generate a single ES2015 build which cannot run in IE 11. So, we have to change the target from es2015 to es5 in your `tsconfig.json`. Otherwise, create a `tsconfig-es5.app.json` configure file, then using `ng serve --configuration es5` to run the serve, more detail information, please check [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455).